# How to estimate the locus of non-zero cohomology for a equivariant toric reflexive sheaf, with a Klyachko description

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, toric-varieties

I am trying to analyze Macaulay2 package "ToricVectorBundles". The package deals with equivariant reflexive sheaves on complete toric varieties. Such a sheaf is described by a set of filtrations of a fixed vector space $V$, each one corresponding to a ray of the fan (Klyachko description). The sheaf is locally free if and only if the filtrations satisfy a certain compatibility condition.

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a reflexive sheaf on a toric variety $X$. If the sheaf is locally free, the package can compute its cohomologies $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})$. The computation is done as follows: 1) function *deltaE* computes the characters $\chi$ of the torus, for which the cohomology can be non-zero, 2) each group $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})_\chi$ is computed for $\chi$ in the range given by *deltaE* ,3) we take the direct sum of all $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})_\chi$ for $\chi$ in the range computed by *deltaE*.

However, if the sheaf is not locally free, the computation fails. The failure is in the function *deltaE*. It works only for locally free sheaves.

My goal is to find another way to estimate the locus $\{ \chi | H^i(X,\mathcal{F})_\chi \neq 0\}$. Can this be done for reflexive sheaves with Klyachko description?

Comment: Hey. I am currently trying to understand Klyachko's description of the cohomology of locally free and possibly reflexive sheaves. Whereas detailed literature regarding Klyachkos filtrations is available (e.g. Perling) i was not able to find any explication of his equivalent construction of the cohomology. Are you aware of such literature?